# Is it possible to reverse engineer a function?

Tags: functions, relations

So I had a question in my mind: if given some specific no. of outputs, can you reverse engineer a function that will give you those values? For eg, if you have sequence of outputs $2, 3, 7, 17$, can you find a function that gives $f(1)=2, f(2)=3, f(3)=7, f(4)=17$?

Is it always possible to do so, or impossible to do, or should the given outputs satisfy a condition to do it systematically without guessing functions at random?

I have somewhat limited math knowledge, so I don't even know how to approach such a problem. If someone can explain it simply, that would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can even find a polynomial that interpolates those values...see [Lagrange Interpolation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html)

Comment: Could [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) be what you have in mind?

Comment: What you are asking is usually called an interpolation, but not a "reverse engineering".

Comment: You can certainly find *a* function which takes those values. Just define it to take those values at the given points, then define it arbitrarily everywhere else.But there's no way to find *the* function $f$ with which you started, unless you have more information. For instance, of you are given $n+1$ points and know that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq n$, then you can find one via polynomial interpolation. Or if you know that it's periodic with a given period and some other properties, you can find an interpolation with sines and cosines. But without further knowledge, it's impossible.

Comment: As essentially stated by @Vercassivelaunos - you can indeed, but the function won't **necessarily** be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Try $f(x)=\dfrac{(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}{(1-2)(1-3)(1-4)}2+\dfrac{(x-1)(x-3)(x-4)}{(2-1)(2-3)(2-4)}3+$

$\dfrac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)}{(3-1)(3-2)(3-4)}7+\dfrac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}{(4-1)(4-2)(4-3)}17.$

Comment: Would you take me through the process by which you arrived at it? Thanks!

Comment: The first term is $0$ when $x=2, 3, $ or $4$ and $2$ when $x=1$; the second term is $0$ when $x=1, 3, $ or $4$ and $3$ when $x=2$; the third term is $0$ when $x=1, 2, $ or $4$ and $7$ when $x=3$; the fourth term is $0$ when $x=1, 2, $ or $3$ and $17$ when $x=4$; add them together to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

If you have integer data, in addition to [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) which has already been mentioned, you can also search the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) database; this may give you polynomial as well as other types of candidate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to find a polynomial that gives the desired values is to look at the differences:

$\begin{matrix}\color{blue}2&\color{orange}1&3&\color{violet}3\\3&4&6&\\7&10\\17\end{matrix}$

(Here the first column has your outputs,

and each subsequent column has the differences of successive entries in the previous column.)

The last column is $\color{violet}3$.  The third column is $3n$.

The second column is $\color{orange}1+3\dfrac{n(n-1)}2=1-\dfrac32n+\dfrac32n^2.$

The first column is $\color{blue}2+(n-1)-\dfrac32\dfrac{n(n-1)}2+\dfrac32\dfrac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}$,

which is $1+n-\dfrac32n^2+\dfrac12n^3$.